# plupload custom variables

Tags: php, jquery, plupload

im using plupload( http://www.plupload.com/index.php ) and i would like to know how can i pass variables in the form to the upload.php file , i tried this:

```
<form  method="post" action="dump.php">
<input type="text" id="event_id"/>
    <div id="uploader">
        <p>You browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5 support.</p>
    </div>
</form>



$(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'flash,html5,browserplus,silverlight,gears,html4',
        url : '../upload.php?event_id='+$("#event_id").val(),
        max_file_size : '1000mb',
        max_file_count: 20, // user can add no more then 20 files at a time
        chunk_size : '1mb',
        unique_names : false,
```

like this(passing the var in a query string) does not work.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Can we see your `upload.php` and what you are trying to do with the query string/`$_GET` vars? Do you have Firebug installed? If not, you should, or this will be hard to debug.

Comment: the upload.php is the original one, i had just change this(to see if the var in the query string was sent), but nothing happened:



$targetDir = 'uploads/'.$_GET["event_id"].'/';

Comment: Try hardcoding a value first: `$targetDir = 'uploads/3/';` and see if that works, it could be a permissions issue creating the directory. Also, open the Firebug console and do a `exit(print_r($_GET))` in your php script and see what happens.

Comment: OK and what about the `print_r()`? Read the whole comment.

Comment: how do you echo a print r in firebug?

Comment: You don't, you do it in your PHP script and view the response in the Firebug console. Each chunk of each file will send a request, and each request will get a response.

Comment: ok i put this in the uploads.php but nothing happens in the console

Comment: "Nothing" happens? I really doubt that. You have an answer, why don't you try that - it looks correct to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe with the `multipart_params` option? Found in the [documentation](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php).

```
multipart_params: {event_id : $("#event_id").val(), param2 : 'value2'}
```

Use `$_REQUEST['event_id']` to get the event id.

Comment: by the way i still cant fix the problem , it's very very hard.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is the answer, ladies and gents. you can tack on multipart_params and keep looking for them in $_POST until you lose your mind, or you can look at $_REQUEST as I just did, finally, at long, long, last. thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send different parameters for each file just do it like that:

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
    up.settings.multipart_params = {"fileid": file.id };
});
```

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me where should I put this bit of code? i mean should i use $('#uploader').bind(...)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I don't think its very hard :)

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
    up.settings.url =  url+"?plupload_id="+file.id;
});
```

to get it:

```
if(isset($_GET['plupload_id']))$id = $_GET['plupload_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. But it adds multiple parameters. Better solution - use UploadFile method instead